# Execute every N command in parallel in shell_exec() in PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'd like to execute N commands in bash in parallel. And then the next N commands after all the commands finish, and then the next N commands …

Because I am not an expert in shell scripting, I have resorted to PHP. But I suspect my code is not doing what I needed optimally:

```
<?php
// d() is a function like var_dump()

d($d);
$ips = array(
"83.149.70.159:13012" => 8,
"37.48.118.90:13082" => 77,
"83.149.70.159:13082" => 77,);

d($ips);
reset($ips);

$prx = "storm";

$f = array();

foreach ($d as $calln) {
$ip = current($ips);
$ipkey = key($ips);
d($ip, $ipkey);
$comd = choose_comd($prx);
d( $comd);

 $f[] = shell_exec($comd);
d($f);

choose_limiting ($prx);

d($GLOBALS['a']);
}


function choose_comd ($prx) {
    d($GLOBALS['calln']);
    switch ($prx) {


        case "storm":
        return "cd /Users/jMac-NEW/HoldingForDO/phub/phubalt_pages && curl -x {$GLOBALS['ipkey']} \"https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchArg={$GLOBALS['calln']}&searchCode=CALL%2B&searchType=1&limitTo=none&fromYear=&toYear=&limitTo=LOCA%3Dall&limitTo=PLAC%3Dall&limitTo=TYPE%3Dall&limitTo=LANG%3Dall&recCount=1200\" >trial_{$GLOBALS['calln']}_out.html 2> trial_{$GLOBALS['calln']}_error.txt &";;

      // more cases ...


}

function choose_limiting ($prx){
    switch ($prx) {
        case "":
        if (!next($ips)) {
    sleep (80);
    reset($ips);
        }
        case "storm":

            if (!isset($GLOBALS['a'])) {
                echo "if";
                $GLOBALS['a'] = 0;
            }
            elseif ($GLOBALS['a'] == current($GLOBALS['ips'])) {
                echo "elseif";
                next($GLOBALS['ips']);
                sleep(80/count($GLOBALS['ips']) - 7); // 80 is the standard
                $GLOBALS['a'] = 0;

            }
            else {
                echo "else";
                $GLOBALS['a']++;

            }


}
}


function trying () {
    $GLOBALS['a']++;
    d($GLOBALS['a']);
}
```

Firstly, I am not sure if running a loop around shell_exec("command… &") will make all the commands run in parallel.

Secondly, the loop runs around all the possible commands, but is made to sleep() with an arbitrary / estimated duration of 70 after every N commands are run with shell_exec(). 70 seconds sleep period may or may not correspond with the completion of all previous N commands that have been executed, but i am just assuming that it will be around there.

May I know if what I have done has fulfilled my aim? If no, why? And what other solution is there?

Actually I do not mind just using bash directly, but the problem is that every iteration of loop is supposed to be fed with a variable $calln from a php array $d populated in earlier parts of the script not shown. If PHP can do what I need, pls stick to PHP.

Comment: Are you waiting for all N commands to finish before doing the next batch because you think it is easier to program, or is there a genuine need to do so? Because in general, it would be quicker to keep N commands running all the time... imagine every group of N commands had N-1 jobs that take 1s and one job that takes 100s.

Comment: @Mark Setchell not sure if I understood you. But any way I'll just say why I do it this way. the commands are curl commands and I have found the server on the other side only able to take N connections concurrently.

Comment: @humanitiesclinic PHP has it's own CURL library wrapper that supports multithread connections, why are you not going to use it?

Comment: @user1597430 oh! thank you! i didn't know about that!